# Text Event Builder Regex not working

Tags: regex, wso2, complex-event-processing

I am new to WSO2 CEP tool. My input comes from JMS message in the below format

```
Latitude=77.77, Longitude=70.12
Latitude=70.12, Longitude60.13
Latitude=xx.xx, Longitude=xx.xx
-
-
-
```

How do I formulate a regex to extract the values for latitude and longitude into individual fields. I tried ^Latitude=in,

But in the system log I am getting the below error
[2014-02-13 20:33:57,158] ERROR - {NativeWorkerPool}  Uncaught exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found

Can someone help me please

Regards
Subbu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if a single line contains:

```
latitude=20.21, longitude=21.20
```

the regex pattern should be

```
"(\d)+\.(\d)+"
```

to return 2 values, 20.21 and 21.20